# automatically renaming files

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a bunch of files (more than 1000) on this like the followings

```
$ ls 
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.BaselineLearnersurfaceForm-dev.lc
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.BaselineLearnersurfaceForm-dev.lex
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.BaselineLearnersurfaceForm-train.lc
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.BaselineLearnersurfaceForm-train.lex
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.BaselineLearnersurfaceForm.lc
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.BaselineLearnersurfaceForm.lex
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.ExpandedLearner.lc
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.ExpandedLearner.lex
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.ExpandedLearnerSVM.lc
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.ExpandedLearnerSVM.lex
....
```

I have to rename these files files by adding a `learners` right before the capitalized name. For example

```
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.BaselineLearnersurfaceForm.lex
```

would change to

```
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.learners.BaselineLearnersurfaceForm.lex
```

and this one

```
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.ExpandedLearner.lc
```

would change to

```
org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.learners.ExpandedLearner.lc
```

Any ideas how to do this automatically?

Comment: I tried, but it isn't trivial (to me at least) how to use it's syntax for this purpose.

Comment: If the word before the Capital Letter of the files are the same, you won't even need regex. A simple linux rename utility will do the job `rename termselector. termselector.learners. org.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in org.*; do
    echo mv "$f" "$( sed 's/\.\([A-Z]\)/.learner.\1/' <<< "$f" )"
done
```

This short loop outputs an `mv` command that renames the files in the manner that you wanted.  Run it as-is first, and when you are certain it's doing what you want, remove the `echo` and run again.

The `sed` bit in the middle takes a filename (`$f`, via a here-string, so this requires `bash`) and replaces the first occurrence of a capital letter after a dot with `.learner.` followed by that same capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [`perl-rename`, sometimes `rename`](http://man.he.net/man1/rename). Not to be confused with [`rename` from util-linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).

It's very good for tasks like this as it takes a perl expression and renames accordingly:

```
perl-rename 's/(?=\.[A-Z])/.learners/' *
```

[You can play with the regex online](https://ideone.com/jDfjtV)

Alternative you can a for loop and `$BASH_REMATCH`:

```
for file in *; do
  [ -e "$file" ] || continue
  [[ "$file" =~ ^([^A-Z]*)(.*)$ ]]
  mv -- "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}learners.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach (useful if you only need to do this one time) is to `ls >dummy` them into a text file `dummy`, and then use find/replace in a text editor to make lines of the form `mv xxx.yyy xxx.learners.yyy`. Then you can simple execute the resulting file with `./dummy`.

The exact find/replace commands depend on the text editor you use, but something like

1. replace `org.` with `mv org.`. That gets you the `mv` in the beginning.
2. replace `mv org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.$1` with `mv org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.$1 org.allenai.ari.solvers.termselector.learner.$1` to duplicate the filename and insert the `learner`.

There is also syntax with a `for`, which can do it probably in one line, (long) but I cannot explain it - try `help for` if you want to learn about it.